# Passing values to the next viewController not working

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, segue

I have this tableViewController that has cells that have one label and an imageView that I need to pass to the next viewController.

on both the class that represents the tableViewCells on the first VC and on the second VC these elements are declared like

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *thumbnail;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fileName;
```

once the disclosure button of one cell is clicked, it triggers `prepareForSegue:sender:`, that I have like this

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

  // the user tapped on the disclosure button of a tableView cell... get the cell
  FileManagerTableViewCell *cell = (FileManagerTableViewCell *)sender;

  // this is the next viewController that will show the cell in detail
  FileManagerDetailVC *detail = [segue destinationViewController];

  detail.thumbnail.image  = cell.thumbnail.image;
  detail.fileName.text    = cell.fileName.text;

  // at this point, `cell.thumbnail.image` and `cell.filename.text` **are not nil**
  // if I check `detail.thumbnail.image` and `detail.filename.text` when the detail
  // is presented, they are nil

}
```

I have tried to create new objects, hoping the problem was cell object being deallocated, so I did this:

```
  detail.thumbnail.image  = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[cell.thumbnail.image CGImage]];
  detail.fileName.text    = [NSString stringWithString:cell.fileName.text];
```

or simply

```
  detail.thumbnail.image  = [cell.thumbnail.image copy];
  detail.fileName.text    = [cell.fileName.text copy];
```

No change.

what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point prepareForSegue is called, view in destination view controller is not loaded yet. Outlets are nil.

Create properties for data instead of ui components, like:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *filenameText;
@property (string, nonatomic) UIImage *thumbnailImage;

//in prepareForSegue
detail.thumbnailImage = cell.thumbnail.image;
detail.filenameText = cell.fileName.text;

// and in viewDidLoad of FileManagerDetailVC
self.thumbnail.image = self.thumbnailImage;
self.fileName.text = self.filenameText
```

That will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Here without creating the thumbnail, fileName object you are assigning values that is the main problem. Just create properties wirh UIImage, NSString types, then assign these values to thumbnail.image and full Name.text then it will work.

Comment: Do you mean by doing this? `  detail.thumbnail.image  = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[cell.thumbnail.image CGImage]];` ? Not working. Objects are nil. I have added more info to my question.